# WaitOne cannot acquire named mutex directly after its creation

Tags: c#, mutex

On certain system (VmWare horizon (latest version) based virtualization) WaitOne cannot acquire mutex directly after its creation. There is a need to wait 100 ms or use WaitOne with time out set to ~100 ms

Code example

```
System.Threading.Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, "MutexName");
bool acquire = mutex.WaitOne(0, false)
```

acquire has false

```
System.Threading.Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, "MutexName");
bool acquire = mutex.WaitOne(100, false)
```

acquire has true

Do you know what this effect occurs, whether it might be related to this specific virtualization environment or whether it can occur on any system. I noticed that  on regular system (bare Windows or HyperV) this issue does not occur.